# Comparing an Array in PowerShell to File Directory Inefficient

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I'm not entirely new to PS but I'm picking it all up on the job without direction which makes learning hard since there are things I don't know that I don't know. That being said, I have a completely functioning script that I would like pointers on how to make faster or possibly an get an entirely different way to do it.

**Problem:**
I have a bunch of photos in a folder that I need to compare to a list of IDs from a SQL table. If I find a match then I need to move that photo into another directory for processing

I know this is inefficient since I'm calling the directory each iteration of the ID loop but I couldn't get it to work if I tried to also create an array of the files to check and then compare the two arrays.

Again, the functionality is great it just isn't quick.

```
CLS

$startDate = Get-Date
$startDate

$photoSourceLocation = "C:\Temp\Photos\Aggregate" #"C:\Temp\Photos\Moved"
$photoDropLocation = "C:\Temp\Photos\Process"

$IdQuery = "SELECT ST.Id FROM SomeTable as ST"


$patients = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $IdQuery -ServerInstance "SQLServer" -Database "DB"
$photos = GCI $photoSourceLocation -File

$patientRaw = $patients | Measure 
$patientCount = $patientRaw.Count

#$PatientCount
$I = 1
$Out= ""

forEach ($patient in $Patients)
        {
        $MovePhoto = GCI $photoSourceLocation -File | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -contains $patient.Id}
        if($MovePhoto)
        {
        Move-Item $movePhoto.FullName -Destination $photoDropLocation 
        }
        #$MovePhoto.FullName
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing photo matches." -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($I/$patientRaw.count*100) #-End $Out
        $I++        
        }

$endDate = Get-Date     
$endDate
```

Comment: since you already have the file list in `$photos`, you can simply test for the `$Patient.ID -in $photos.BaseName`. it may save you time to create that basename collection in advance.

Comment: My original intent was to create two arrays, compare, and then take action. Try as I might I couldn't get said comparison between two arrays to function. I don't have those code snippets anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the file in each iteration is probably what makes it so slow. You should get the files only once (look at the comments):

## NOT TESTED

```
cls
($startDate = Get-Date)

$photoSourceLocation = "C:\Temp\Photos\Aggregate"
$photoDropLocation = "C:\Temp\Photos\Process"

$idQuery = "SELECT Id FROM SomeTable"
# select ids as plain string array (makes it easier for "contains")
$patientIds = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $idQuery -ServerInstance "SQLServer" -Database "DB" | foreach { $_.Id.ToString() })

# get all photos only once
# make it a list so we can remove items
$photos = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(gci $photoSourceLocation -File)
$i = 0
foreach ($id in $patientIds) {
    # check the list of photos
    for ($p = 0; $p -lt $photos.Count; $p++) {
        $photos = $photos[$p]
        if ($photo.BaseName.Contains($id)) {
            # match found: move photo
            Move-Item $photo.FullName -Destination $photoDropLocation 
            # remove from list, so we have to search less next time
            $photos.RemoveAt($p)
            $p--
            # if there can only be one photo, we could stop looking here:
            # break
        }
    }
    $i++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing photo matches." -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($i * 100 / $patientIds.Count)
}

($endDate = Get-Date)
```

Notes:

- If you should loop the ids in the outer and photos in the inner loop, or rather the other way round, depends on your use case.
- Un-comment the "break" if there can only be one photo per id
- Removing the elements from the list makes it shorter, and there are less items to check. But it also requires the array to be resized. Test it and compare both alternatives, maybe *not* removing the item is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to test for a match between items in a CSV import and the items in a collection of file names. It depends on the way that `-match` works when used against a collection instead of a single item.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
ID
Zero000
Alpha111
Bravo222
Charlie333
Santa666
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# fake reading in a list of file names
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem
$FileList = @(
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Alpha111.jpg'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Charlie333.jpg'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Santa666.jpg'
    )

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # this depends on there only being ONE matching file
    $FoundFile = $FileList -match $IS_Item.ID

    if ($FoundFile)
        {
        'Found a file for     = {0}' -f $IS_Item.ID
        '    The file name is = {0}' -f $FoundFile.Name
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('No matching file was found for {0}' -f $IS_Item.ID)
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
WARNING: No matching file was found for Zero000
Found a file for     = Alpha111
    The file name is = Alpha111.jpg
WARNING: No matching file was found for Bravo222
Found a file for     = Charlie333
    The file name is = Charlie333.jpg
Found a file for     = Santa666
    The file name is = Santa666.jpg
```

Comment: All operators work on collections, but can produce multiple results. Use with caution. If there can be at most one match, it should be safe in this case.

Comment: @marsze - yes, the difference in behavior can ruin ones day if it comes as a surprise. [*grin*]

Comment: I'm not at my office today and won't be able to test these until tomorrow but this looks a lot like what I was attempting to do but failing at. Thanks. It looks like I could put a Move-Item in the if when a match is found or even put the matches into another array and then bulk move at the end.

Comment: @PerfectPearl - i would likely put the action in the `if`, but gathering all the info and doing the actions on that collection would add another level of control that may prove useful. [*grin*]